# RAD project build issue: The project was not built due to "Could not delete

Tags: eclipse, rad

I am using RAD 7.5 on a Windows XP m/c. Whenever I try to do a clean up/build the project, I get a message saying

`The project was not built due to "Could not delete 'D:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\project\exe\EXE\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\BusinessRules.properties'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent`

To overcome this problem, I need to stop the server, manually delete this file & then build & restart the server. Any idea why I am facing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced the issue in RAD 8.0, but not nearly as consistently as you. A second build attempt nearly always resolves the problem for me.

Although there are a number of references to this issue on the Eclipse bug tracking site, none of the bugs I've read have a definitive answer on the cause. There is some speculation that it may be due to a file handle leak. The problem appears to have begun around Eclipse version 3.6.1. I'm not sure exactly which Eclipse version RAD 7.5 is based on, but I believe it is 3.6.1 or later.

Does the issue only occur when the application is deployed and the server is running? I was wondering if you'd gotten the same results with the server shut down.

Unfortunately, the only concrete suggestions I can offer are to try refreshing the project frequently, and perhaps creating a new workspace -- its a bit of a hack, but a creating a fresh workspace has fixed a few really odd RAD issues I've encountered.

Here are a couple of the bug reports from the Eclipse bug tracking site:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=309235
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=332607